# How to change Bone display color in 4.0

Tags: interface, bones

How does one change the bone display color in 4.0? I simply can't find the option. Where are the buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bone display color can be accessed in both **Edit** and **Pose** mode in the **Bone Properties** tab (the green bone icon)

[image]

Comment: This change not only adds more work but also prevents changing the color of multiple bones.